# Posting to a Sheetlabs API with Axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am working with [Sheetlabs](https://sheetlabs.com/#/) to turn a Google Sheet into a full API. I'm having trouble finding helpful information online besides the Sheetlabs [documentation](https://sheetlabs.com/#/docs), because it seems like a fairly small service at this point.

I'm using axios within a custom function in Twilio to post information to our Sheetlabs API. The API requires HTTP Basic authentication.

I've tried all sorts of variations on my axios call, trying to follow the [Sheetlabs SwaggerHub Documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/sheetlabs/sheetlabs-admin/1.0.0#/records/createRecord) but I'm running out of ideas.

```
const url = 'https://sheetlabs.com/records/{organization}/{dbName}';

const postData = {
  trackingid: `${trackingUrl}`,
  phonenumber: `${userPhoneNumber}`
}

const authParams = {
  username: //sheetlabs email,
  password: //access token
}

// axios function
axios.post(url, postData, {auth: authParams}).then(response => {
  console.log('response: ', response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('axios sheetlabs post error catch: ', err);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll do my best to provide you with any additional information you need.

Comment: What is the exact problem at hand? Is there a specific obstacle or error that you're facing?

Comment: Well the information isn't being added to the google sheet, but I'm also not getting any logs in the Twilio console from the response or the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Sheetlabs Support and at this time they don't support adding new records to a Google Sheet via posts. Could have sworn I saw that capability in their documentation and API though. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX by default sends data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, but Axios sends it as JSON. I mention AJAX because in the [example page](https://app.sheetlabs.com/#/services/doc/ACME/getDomain#examples) they're using `$.ajax` to do a network request.

Axios mentions this default on their Github [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) and it's something I've run into on many servers who aren't sent up to receive JSON. It might be worth a shot to try doing an `npm install qs` and seeing if it helps you out:

```
const qs = require('qs');
axios.post(url, qs.stringify(postData), {auth: authParams}).then(response => {
  console.log('response: ', response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('axios sheetlabs post error catch: ', err);
});
```